# Direct2D Not Linking Whole Library in C++Builder

Tags: c++, linker, c++builder, direct2d, c++builder-10.1-berlin

I've got a C++ project in Embarcadero RAD Studio 10.1 Berlin.  The project is setup to use Direct2D. Canvas drawing works just fine with the `TDirect2DCanvas` class. Everything renders smoothly. However, I need to use render targets. I am getting a linking error when I try to do this. For example, when I try this:

```
canvas->RenderTarget->SetTransform(D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Rotation(15.0, D2D1PointF(100, 100)));
```

I get the following linking error:

```
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'D2D1MakeRotateMatrix' referenced from C:\DP\TRUNK\SRC\CLIENTSIDE\APPLICATIONS\VIEWER\WIN32\DEBUG\MIMAGE.OBJ
```

I thought C++Builder was supposed to already be setup to link against Direct2D if I just included the headers. Can anyone help me link against the appropriate files?

Comment: Please [edit] your question title so it contains something meaningful. Direct2D and C++Builder are both available from the tags you've added, and Embarcadero is irrelevant (unless you know of another company who owns C++ Builder currently). Removing those from your title leaves *in*, which clearly has no meaning alone. Your title should describe the problem you're having or question you're asking in a way that will be relevant to future readers here who see it in a search result.

Comment: I've updated my post.

Comment: Maybe we should mark every question as duplicate as they are all related to coding? That would certainly keep stackoverflow neat and tidy :).
Yes, you do need to link to d2d1.lib, this is mentioned somewhere in the Help. Keep in mind even after all these years, BCB still only supports D2D 1.0...

Comment: Per the [`D2D1MakeRotateMatrix()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368049.aspx), it is implemented in `D2d1.dll` and referenced by `D2d1.lib`, so make sure you are linking in `D2d1.lib` to your executable, either by adding the `.lib` file to your project (it is located in the `$(BDS)\lib\win32\release\psdk` folder), or by adding a `#pragma comment(lib, "D2d1.lib")` statement in your code (and make sure the PSDK folder is in your project's library search path).